# Linear independence or dependence of a set $\{z_2-y,z_3-y\}\subset \mathbb R^3.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\{z_2,z_3\}\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ be a linearly independent set. Let $y\in \mathbb R^3$ such that $y \neq z_2, y\neq z_3$ then can we say that the set $\{z_2-y,z_3-y\}$ is linearly independent subset of $\mathbb R^3?$

I need some help.
I tried with usual definition of being linearly independent but couldn't get any final answer.

Thanks.

Comment: To say that [tex]r_1[/tex] and [tex]r_2[/tex] are "linearly  independent" means that if [tex]ar_1+ br_2= 0[/tex] then a= b.   Suppose there exist a and b such that [tex]a(r_1- y)+ b(r_2- y)= ar_1- ay+ br_2- by= ar_1+ br_2- (a+ b)y= 0

Comment: For them to be linearly dependent, you’ll need $z_1,z_2,y$ linearly dependent. So, start with $y=az_1+bz_2.$. You’ll want $z_1-y=(1-a)z_1-bz_2$ and $z_2-y=-az_1+(1-b)z_2$ linearly dependent.

Comment: @user247327 learn to use MathJax. `$…$` instead of `[tex]…[tex]`

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) is the link to the mathJax documentation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : what if $y$ is not in span of $\{z_2,z_3\}$?

Comment: Then $z_1-y,z_2-y$ can’t possibly be linearly dependent if $z_1,z_2$ are independent. @MADmind

Comment: Alright . Actually I got the answer now. In my main problem $y$ is in the interior of affine hull of the set $\{z_2,z_3,z_4\}$ where $z_4$ is another point of $\mathbb R^3$. So in this case the set $\{z_2-y,z_3-y\}$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: Did you mean “affine hull?” Because there is no interior to an affine hull. There is a notion of an interior to a convex hull.

Comment: Suppose you choose $y = a z_2 + (1 - a) z_3 $, then $ z_2 - y = (1 - a) z_2 - (1 - a) z_3 = (1-a) (z_2 - z_3) $ and $ z_3 - y = - a z_2 + a z_3 = -a (z_2 - z_3) $ , so you will have $(z_2 - y) $ and $ (z_3 - y) $ linearly dependent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Actually $y=c_2z_2+c_3z_3+c_4z_4$ where $c_2+c_3+c_4=1$ and $c_i>0$ for every $i=2,3,4.$

Comment: @HosamHajjir : yes

Comment: Yeah, that’s the definition of convex hull, not affine hull. Specifically, it is the interior of the convex hull in the affine hull. The affine hull of three non-colinear points is a plane. At least according to Wikipedia. @MADmind